# Detect if PhoneGap/Cordova when loading external URL

Tags: javascript, cordova

I'm developing a PhoneGap/Cordova app which is acting as a wrapper to load and display an external URL to make a mobile website into an app using the code below:

```
window.open('http://www.website.com', '_self', 'location=no');
```

There are some elements of the mobile website which I'd like to remove on load, which aren't applicable when viewing in the app (such as "view full site").

Is there any way to detect, from the external website's JavaScript, if the page is being viewed inside a PhoneGap/Cordova app?

Comment: You could get some luck with the `user-agent`, how about adding a hash? `website.com/index.html#cordova=true`.

Comment: InAppBrowser has an `injectScript()` method, you could probably use that to inject a flag into the global context of the webpage, so you're external site could just check `if( window.cordovaExists )` or something.

Comment: @JamesWong Great idea about the hash, will try it - but `user-agent` won't work, as all features of the mobile site must still be accessible through the regular mobile browser when these "view full site" links are required

Comment: @MBillau - do you mean `executeScript()`? http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/cordova_inappbrowser_inappbrowser.md.html#executeScript

Comment: Yeah, https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/blob/dev/doc/index.md#executescript
I've never tried it but it might be possible. If for some reason you can't actually access the window object of the page to set globals, you could maybe append a hidden DOM node or something to the page.

Comment: @MBillau Sounds good... will try that as a more elegant solution, but the hash is certainly a backup.

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I used a query string parameter on the PHP page to inform it that it was being loaded inside an app.

I then used a cookie to remember it for the session and load some Javascript code if the query string is defined or if the cookie is set.